# Python BeautifulSoup - trouble parsing table from webpage

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to parse the table data from the following site:
[Pricing data](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) and create a dataframe with all of the table values (vCPU, Memory, Storage, Price). However, with the following code, I can't seem to find the table on the page. Can someone help me figure out how to parse out the values?

Using the pd.read_html, an error shows up that no tables are found.

```html
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


url = "https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/"
r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
data=[]
tables = soup.find_all('table')


df = pd.read_html(url)
```

Comment: I think the table is loaded through AJAX. Look inside network inspector in the browser and search for any ajax calls inside page.

Answer (score 0):

If your having trouble because of dynamic content a good work around is selenium, it simulates browser experience so you dont have to worry about managing cookies and other problems that come with dynamic web content. I was able to scrape the page with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/')
sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
driver.close()
data=[]
tables = soup.find_all('table')
print(tables)
```